# Regex Help - group within a group one or more times

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am looking for some help. I am unsure if it is possible to match an outside group and also match inside the group if exists.

for example:

10/22/2021  8:56:35 test Warning ID: 111 OD: 00:00:01 blah blah blah blah

I want to

- group date:          10/22/2022
- group time:          8:56:35
- group proc:          test
- group log_level:     Warning
- group ID(if exist):      ID: 111
- group message:          test Warning ID: 111 OD: 00:00:01 blah blah
  blah blah

Regex appears to almost work but fails if ID is not present. I only want to capture ID if we match, else just capture the message.

```
^(?<date>(?:\d+)\/\d+\/\d+)\s+(?<time>(?:\d+:){2}\d+)\s+(?<proc>\w+)\s(?<log_level>\w+)\s(?<message>.*(?:ID: (?<ID>\d+)).*)$
```

I want to match the ID group 0 or 1 times (?) but when i add ? to the group it breaks the regex for the message group. ie:

```
^(?<date>(?:\d+)\/\d+\/\d+)\s+(?<time>(?:\d+:){2}\d+)\s+(?<proc>\w+)\s(?<log_level>\w+)\s(?<message>.*(?:ID: (?<ID>\d+))?.*)$
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?<date>(?:\d+)\/\d+\/\d+)\s+(?<time>(?:\d+:){2}\d+)\s+(?<proc>\w+)\s(?<log_level>\w+)\s(?<message>.*?(?:ID: (?<ID>\d+).*)?)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x9aLyh/1).

The only change is in Group "message" pattern, that now looks like `(?<message>.*?(?:ID: (?<ID>\d+).*)?)`. It matches

- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as **few** as possible
- `(?:ID: (?<ID>\d+).*)?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches

  - `ID:`  - a fixed string
  - `(?<ID>\d+)` - Group "ID": one or more digits
  - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as *many* as possible.